# Bypass end of memory problem for huge python list and histogram

Tags: python, list, memory, histogram

I have to work with a huge list of python: I have two lists of almost 50.000 elements and I have to subtract each of the second one to each of the first one and then produce an histogram. The fact is that of course I don't have enough memory to store 50.000x50.000 elements, so I have to find an alternative way. What I did (and works for shorter lists) was just to do each difference and to store them in a list that then I plotted with matplotlib histogram function, but I think I need to produce like a live histogram so I don't have to store each difference. I've tried to do an histogram in this way:

```
        for i in range (0,x):
            if ((i*H)<r<(H+i*H)):
            d[i]=d[i]+1
```

where x is the number of bins and H the bin size, but is very slow and not actually usable. Could you help me with other ideas? There is a way to plot a sort of "live histogram"? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Counter (from collections),you can obtain the count of difference dynamically without storing all the differences.

```
import random
list1 = [random.randrange(1,1000) for _ in range(50000)]
list2 = [random.randrange(1,1000) for _ in range(50000)]

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(list2)

for diff in [1,2,3,4]: # the differences to display
    count = sum(counts[v-diff] for v in list1)
    print(diff,":",count)

1 : 2496311
2 : 2496457
3 : 2494224
4 : 2487048
```

What this does is store the count of distinct values of the second list in a Counter dictionary.  This allows you to quickly obtain the number of element pairs for any given difference value.  Since your histogram is not going to show 2.5G differences at once, this can greatly reduce the amount of calculations by only computing the difference counts that are actually needed.

Note that I assumed that your elements were integer values.  This makes the value of differences predictable within a range.  If your values are floats, you will need to work with ranges for the differences (which will bring the problem back to a simpler integer process).